# Using Rails 5, how can I make FriendlyId append a -"count+1" to duplicate slugs instead of a UUID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-url, slug, friendly-id

Apparently FriendlyId has changed it's previously default method of appending a numeric sequence to duplicate slugs (which is what I want) to now use UUID:

```
Previous versions of FriendlyId appended a numeric sequence to make slugs unique, but this was removed to simplify using FriendlyId in concurrent code.
```

This functionality is not something I'm interested in at this time and would much prefer to have the original method that results in a cleaner URL. I found a similar question where [someone provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25380607/523051) the below code to override the friendlyId `normalize_friendly_id` method to get to the functionality I'm after, but using it results in an error (`wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`):

```
def normalize_friendly_id
  count = self.count "name = #{name}"
  super + "-" + count if name > 0
end
```

I attempted to "convert" this into a friendlyId "candidate" but I don't really know what I'm doing and the below doesn't work. Any thoughts on how I could tweak the name_candidate method to produce the result I'm afer?

```
class Folder < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name_candidates, use: [ :slugged, :scoped ], scope: :account_id

  has_ancestry

  belongs_to :account
  has_many :notes, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true

  # # https://stackoverflow.com/a/25380607/523051
  # # overrride friendlyId to append -number to duplicate folders instead of uuid's
  # def normalize_friendly_id
  #   count = self.count "name = #{name}"
  #   super + "-" + count if name > 0
  # end

  def name_candidates
    append_number = self.count "name = #{name}" if name > 0
    [
      :name,
      :name, append_number
    ]
  end
end
```

Note I am utilizing the `:scoped` functionality of friendlyId, so checks for existing folder names should be correctly scoped to `:account_id`.

Answer (score 3):

friendly_id 5 now has a slug_candidates that lets you customize the slug.

So to generate a sequential slug you could do:

```
friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

def slug_candidates
  [:name, :name_and_sequence]
end

def name_and_sequence
  slug = normalize_friendly_id(name)
  sequence = Model.where("slug like '#{slug}--%'").count + 2
  "#{slug}--#{sequence}"
end
```

This is discussed in the following issue:
https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/480

[According to the author, sequential slugs are bad for performance](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/480#issuecomment-34643306).

Comment: The answer by @chrickso is cleaner unless you need to customize the sequential numbering.

Answer (score 2):

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34730277/523051) in a different thread and, because the module has since been implemented into friendlyId, all I had to do was change the `use: :slugged` to `use: sequentially_slugged` to produce the functionality i was after.

```
class Folder < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [ :sequentially_slugged, :scoped ], scope: :account_id
end
```

Comment: `friendly_id :name, use: :sequentially_slugged`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because normalize_friendly_id takes a parameter : 
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/FriendlyId%2FSlugged%3Anormalize_friendly_id

you must pass the name as a parameter when you call the super

Comment: thanks. still am stuck though as to where/what I pass in. if i add name as a parameter like def normalize_friendly_id(name) then i get past the wrong number of arguments error and get "undefined method `count' for #<Folder:0x00007f97fc812680>"

Comment: Note, that inside `normalize_friendly_id ` you are scoped to the instance of `Folder`. Try `self.class.count`.

Comment: @SergiiK changing the above normalize_friendly_id self.count to self.class.count generates this error: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "test" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(name = test) FROM "folders" ^ : SELECT COUNT(name = test) FROM "folders" with "test" being the string I input into the form that it is attempting to slug